# Spatially deleting features using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

For example, I have two separate point feature classes. I want to delete points of one feature class if it is within x distance of a point from the other feature class.

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a three step process. You need to first select your point to search from, find and select the points to delete, then you delete those selected points. You haven't said you need to *automate* this, so I'll answer manually running tools within ArcGIS Pro.

1. Select the point from your feature class using the **Select** tool.
2. Open the **Select by Location** tool, and change the *Relationship* to *Within a distance* and update the *Search Distance*. Use the *Selecting features* to choose the feature class with your single point selected. The *Input features* should be the feature class of points you wish to delete.
3. Run the **Delete Features** tool. It will only delete the selected features.